# Always running TCP server on a webserver

Tags: tcp

I want to create a TCP Server which is always running on a webserver, so that I can connect using web browser as a client, to push data to the server. Server wont send back anything to the client, just will keep on listening whatever a web browser has to say. In which language should I code, and please give some example code also. I think Java is a good language for such task, but how will I embed it in my web based domain server?

Comment: I think you suffer from a great confusion of what TCP is. A webserver is a program implemeting the HTTP protocol. A client (=webbrowser) connects to the webserver by TCP, speaking the HTTP protocol. TCP is a protocol building upon IP, implementing things like three way handshake, congestion control, retransmission. IP is what makes the Internet tick, i.e. packets and routes.

Comment: That question is a little broad, with argumentative answers regarding the language to be used, while at the same time asking others to basically provide working code. Also note that not sending a HTTP response to the client will not provide exactly a smooth user experience.

Answer (score 1):

As always, you should code the server in whatever language you are familiar with. Obviously, for most of us, using a language like C++, Ruby, or Java is easier for a tcp server than, say, Postscript, but that has been done, too.

As for getting the server to run on the same machine as your web server, that depends on what your web server is running on. But it's a question for superuser anyway. (And if you don't know how to start a server on that machine, what exactly are you doing administering a server connected to the internet in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

I used Java to code my proxy server, that is simple and good I can handle all the requests and responses.